# Manipulating struct/vec in rust

Tags: rust

I'm trying to build a small rust program to track my trades.

I have a csv like this:

```
"ID","Time","Market","Side","Order Type","Size","Price","Total","Fee","Fee Currency","TWAP"
    "9388115186","2022-08-03T00:23:23.579534+00:00","WAVES-PERP","buy","Market","45","5.612","252.54","0.17147466","USD","false"
    "9387838330","2022-08-03T00:10:59.413454+00:00","WAVES-PERP","sell","Market","45","5.7175","257.2875","0.1746982125","USD","false"
    "9386385927","2022-08-02T21:49:32.641156+00:00","WAVES-PERP","sell","Market","76","5.7805","439.318","0.298296922","USD","false"
    "9386350793","2022-08-02T21:46:09.927443+00:00","WAVES-PERP","buy","Market","76","5.758","437.608","0.297135832","USD","false"
    "9386323186","2022-08-02T21:43:54.643217+00:00","WAVES-PERP","buy","Market","81.5","5.7565","469.15475","0.31855607525","USD","false"
    "9386299652","2022-08-02T21:39:22.444948+00:00","WAVES-PERP","sell","Market","80","5.7335","458.68","0.31144372","USD","false"
    "9386299650","2022-08-02T21:39:22.444948+00:00","WAVES-PERP","sell","Market","1.5","5.7335","8.60025","0.00583956975","USD","false"
    "9386280602","2022-08-02T21:35:45.667046+00:00","WAVES-PERP","sell","Market","80","5.738","459.04","0.31168816","USD","false"
    "9386122733","2022-08-02T21:12:10.951077+00:00","WAVES-PERP","buy","Market","5","5.713","28.565","0.019395635","USD","false"
    "9386122731","2022-08-02T21:12:10.951077+00:00","WAVES-PERP","buy","Market","75","5.713","428.475","0.290934525","USD","false"
    "9386106303","2022-08-02T21:10:54.380241+00:00","WAVES-PERP","sell","Market","81","5.722","463.482","0.314704278","USD","false"
    "9386096811","2022-08-02T21:10:06.837460+00:00","WAVES-PERP","buy","Market","81","5.7285","464.0085","0.3150617715","USD","false"
    "9384995941","2022-08-02T19:13:33.987751+00:00","WAVES-PERP","sell","Market","8","5.7255","45.804","0.031100916","USD","false"
    "9384995939","2022-08-02T19:13:33.987751+00:00","WAVES-PERP","sell","Market","41.5","5.7255","237.60825","0.16133600175","USD","false"
    "9384994161","2022-08-02T19:13:07.187765+00:00","WAVES-PERP","buy","Market","43.5","5.74","249.69","0.16953951","USD","false"
    "9384994159","2022-08-02T19:13:07.187765+00:00","WAVES-PERP","buy","Market","6","5.7395","34.437","0.023382723","USD","false"
    "9384980319","2022-08-02T19:11:57.794552+00:00","WAVES-PERP","buy","Market","36.5","5.7315","209.19975","0.14204663025","USD","false"
    "9384822588","2022-08-02T19:01:35.959545+00:00","WAVES-PERP","sell","Market","36.5","5.7395","209.49175","0.14224489825","USD","false"
    "9384765277","2022-08-02T18:57:51.339876+00:00","WAVES-PERP","buy","Market","78","5.736","447.40799999999996","0.303790032","USD","false"
    "9384665536","2022-08-02T18:51:33.017459+00:00","WAVES-PERP","sell","Market","64.5","5.771","372.2295","0.2527438305","USD","false"
    "9384665534","2022-08-02T18:51:33.017459+00:00","WAVES-PERP","sell","Market","13.5","5.7725","77.92875","0.05291362125","USD","false"
```

I want my cli program to print the profit of each trade, which is basic sell - buy - fee. I can make it to sum all the trades, but I want it to print every trade individually so I can make a more detailed report. I have no idea how to write this logic.

The program I wrote that sums with every trade:

```
use clap::{Parser};
use csv::Reader;
use serde::Deserialize;
use std::{fs::File};

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[allow(non_snake_case)]
struct FtxTransactions {
    Market: String,
    Fee: f64,
    Total: f64,
    Side: String,
}

#[derive(Parser, Debug)]
#[clap(author, version, about, long_about = None)]
struct Args {
    #[clap(short, long, value_parser)]
    exchange: String,
}

fn main() {
    let args = Args::parse();

    let mut file_ftx = Reader::from_path("./src/csv/scalp_trades.csv").unwrap();

    match args.exchange.as_str() {
        "ftx_total" => println!("ftx profit: {:.3} usd", ftx_total(&mut file_ftx)),
        _ => println!("no function"),
    };
}

fn ftx_total(args: &mut Reader<File>) -> f64 {
    let mut value_sum = 0.0;
    for result in args.deserialize::<FtxTransactions>() {
        let record = result.unwrap();
        if record.Market == "WAVES-PERP" && record.Side == "buy" {
            value_sum = value_sum - record.Total - record.Fee;
        }
        if record.Market == "WAVES-PERP" && record.Side == "sell" {
            value_sum = value_sum + record.Total - record.Fee;
        }
    }
    return value_sum;
}
```

Comment: Do you want this function to *print* the data, or do you want to return a vector of each transaction (either as a f64 or a struct with more details)?

Comment: I just want the individual results of each trade. Whatever way is easier. Like:
trade 1 $10
trade 2 -$10

Comment: Can you please include your `FtxTransactions` struct and which `Reader` and `File` you're using ([edit] the question, don't just add it as a comment)?

Comment: Done, posted the full program.

Comment: Are you sure that's it? Using the latest version of each crate and Rust edition 2021, this code does not compile on my machine. It's possible you have older versions of these crates (clap, csv, and serde), so can you also include the applicable parts of your `Cargo.toml` file? I'll start working on something assuming an iterator of `FtxTransactions`

Comment: yes it compiles here. Dependecies are:
csv = "1.1.6"
serde = { version = "1.0.137", features = ["derive"] }
clap = { version = "3.2.15", features = ["derive"] }

and you need a csv folder with a scalp_trades.csv file

Comment: run like this: 
cargo run -- -e ftx_total

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I am new to Rust, so this might not be best practices, but it works ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

```rust
fn ftx_vec(args: &mut Reader<File>) -> Vec<f64> {
    args.deserialize::<FtxTransactions>()
        .map(|result| {
            let record = result.unwrap();
            if record.Market == "WAVES-PERP" && record.Side == "buy" {
                -record.Total - record.Fee
            } else if record.Market == "WAVES-PERP" && record.Side == "sell" {
                record.Total - record.Fee
            } else {
                0.0
            }
        })
        .collect()
}
```

This expects the file reader as your other function (you probably want to parse this once in its own function, and make these functions just take in an unmutable reference to the vector of `FtxTransactions`), and returns a vector of 64-bit floats.

just modify your match statement to call this with the exchange arg `"ftx_vec"` (you can rename to whatever you want) and print it prettily .

```rust
    match args.exchange.as_str() {
        "ftx_total" => println!("ftx profit: {:.3} usd", ftx_total(&mut file_ftx)),
        "ftx_vec" => for (i, record) in ftx_vec(&mut file_ftx).iter().enumerate() {
            println!("Transaction #{}: ${:?} USD", i, record)
        }
        _ => println!("no function"),
    };
```

Output from your inputs:

```
Transaction #0: $-252.71147466 USD
Transaction #1: $257.1128017875 USD
Transaction #2: $439.01970307799996 USD
Transaction #3: $-437.905135832 USD
Transaction #4: $-469.47330607525 USD
Transaction #5: $458.36855628 USD
Transaction #6: $8.59441043025 USD
Transaction #7: $458.72831184 USD
Transaction #8: $-28.584395635 USD
Transaction #9: $-428.76593452500003 USD
Transaction #10: $463.167295722 USD
Transaction #11: $-464.3235617715 USD
Transaction #12: $45.772899084 USD
Transaction #13: $237.44691399825 USD
Transaction #14: $-249.85953951 USD
Transaction #15: $-34.460382722999995 USD
Transaction #16: $-209.34179663025 USD
Transaction #17: $209.34950510175 USD
Transaction #18: $-447.71179003199995 USD
Transaction #19: $371.9767561695 USD
Transaction #20: $77.87583637875 USD
```

you probably would want to round to nearest cent, and possibly print out `i + 1` instead of `i` to be `1`-indexed

Comment: Maybe I explained a bit wrong. It's supposed to add the transactions in sequence (buy or sell), that's the problem I'm having, I have no idea how to implement this logic. Would be like:

Transaction 1 = -252 (buy)
Transaction 2 = 257 + 439 (sell)
Transacton 3 = -437-469 (buy)

Then:

Transaction 2 - 1 (buy - sell)

(but I think this part I can do it)